# How to compute occurrencies of specific value and its percentage for each column based on condition pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, find-occurrences

I have the following dataframe df, in which I highlighted in green the cells with values of interest:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmitR.jpg)
and I would like to obtain for each columns (therefore by considering the whole dataframe) the following statistics: the occurrence of a value less or equal to 0.5 (green cells in the dataframe) -Nan values are not to be included- and its percentage in the considered columns in order to use say 50% as benchmark.

For the point asked I tried with value_count like (df['A'].value_counts()/df['A'].count())*100, but this returns the partial result not the way I would and only for specific columns; I was also thinking about using filter or lamba function like df.loc[lambda x: x <= 0.5] but cleary that is not the result I wanted.

The goal/output will be a dataframe as shown below in which are displayed just the columns that "beat" the benchmark (recall: at least (half) 50% of their values <= 0.5).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddcK8.jpg)
e.g. in column A the count would be 2 and the percentage: 2/3 * 100 = 66%, while in column B the count would be 4 and the percentage: 4/8 * 100 = 50%. (The same goes for columns X, Y and Z). On the other hand in column C where 2/8 *100 = 25% won't beat the benchmark and therefore not considered in the output.

Is there a suitable way to achieve this IYHO? Apologies in advance if this was a kinda duplicated question but I found no other questions able to help me out, and thx to any saviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have understood your ask in the below code...
It would be good if you could provide an expected output in your question so that it is easier to follow.

Anyways the first part of the code below is just set up so can be ignored as you already have your data set up.
Basically I have created a quick function for you that will return the percentage of values that are under a threshold that you can define.
This function is called in a loop of all the columns within your dataframe and if this percentage is more than the output threshold (again you can define it) it will keep it for actually outputting.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
import datetime

### SET UP ###

base = datetime.datetime.today()
date_list = [base - datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(10)]

def rand_num_list(length):
    peak = [round(random.uniform(0,1),1) for i in range(length)] + [0] * (10-length)
    random.shuffle(peak)
    return peak


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'A':rand_num_list(3),
        'B':rand_num_list(5),
        'C':rand_num_list(7),
        'D':rand_num_list(2),
        'E':rand_num_list(6),
        'F':rand_num_list(4)
    },
    index=date_list
)

df = df.replace({0:np.nan})

##############

print(df)

def less_than_threshold(thresh_df, thresh_col, threshold):
    if len(thresh_df[thresh_col].dropna()) == 0:
        return 0

    return len(thresh_df.loc[thresh_df[thresh_col]<=threshold]) / len(thresh_df[thresh_col].dropna())

output_dict = {'cols':[]}
col_threshold = 0.5
output_threshold = 0.5
for col in df.columns:
    if less_than_threshold(df, col, col_threshold) >= output_threshold:
        output_dict['cols'].append(col)
    
df_output = df.loc[:,output_dict.get('cols')]

print(df_output)
```

Hope this achieves your goal!

Comment: thanks for your answer, I edited my question to clarify and display my desired output. Your code does quite the job given that the number of columns in the df is decreased as expected, however it didn't exclude some columns where the values less or equal to 0.5 are less than the 50% of the overall number of values in the column considered. If for ex. column H: [0.3, 0.6, 0.7], since there is only a value less than 0.5 (that is 0.3) out of 3 total values (therefore less than 50% threshold, in fact 1/3 * 100 = 33%), this columns should be dropped from the desired output dataframe.

Comment: Hi @ArthurK are you able to share the values of column H in your data? I have just mocked up your example and my code did indeed drop this column

Comment: Column H was just a dummy example, I was just trying to put it into words, however your code works good, instead I get "ZeroDivisionError: division by zero" error when I applied it to my df; if I remove dropna() from "return len(thresh_df.loc[thresh_df[thresh_col]<=threshold]) / len(thresh_df[thresh_col].dropna())", it runs but shows also  unwanted columns.

Comment: @ArthurK just added in a small if clause to handle for the zero division errors

Comment: Yeah, it did the trick thx; however I've just noticed that also your code sometimes fails to achieve the task, that is it fails to display a column which should be printed especially when nan values are many say 8 out of 10 (there is a column having 0.5, 0.7 and the remaining are nan values but should be considered as eligible since 0.5 is 50% of the available values after all),  I don't know why tho.

Comment: Ah apologies @ArthurK, I have re-edited my answer. All it needed was greater than OR equal to when checking against the output_threshold, whereas my first version just looked at greater than. if this works for you then an upvote and accepting of my answer would be much appreciated :)